# Remove 160 char limit on S5

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, toast-notifications

Is there a way to remove the 160 char limit when replying to a text through the 'toast' method on the galaxy s5 **without root**

Comment: What exactly is "the toast method"?

Comment: @DanHulme I presumed it was the toast notification where the notification is placed above anything else, so if your in a game for example the game will not stop the notification will simply appear

Comment: Yes, I know what a toast notification is. You mentioned that you reply to texts through "the toast method". What exactly do you do?

Comment: @DanHulme When the notification comes up, there's an option to reply within the notification, the problem is that it only allows 160 characters

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is wondering about this particular problem

There is as far as I know no way to do this however there is an app called 'QKSMS' that has a quick reply mode which is similar to the stock version which does not have a character limit